# Bash bad substitution

Tags: bash, substitution, string-substitution

I'm working on a tiny script for school that has for goal to get a bmp file's size (file as parameter) using a single command line (no ; or &&)

So I did this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "size : ${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):6:2}${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):4:2}${$(xxd -p -seek     02 -l 4 $1):2:2}${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):0:2} bytes"
```

But when executed (using bash or execution) it returns the following error :

```
./script.sh: line 3: size : ${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):6:2}${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):4:2}${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):2:2}${$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 $1):0:2} bytes: bad substitution
```

Which I do not know how to get rid of, may you guys help me solve this problem ?

Comment: There's no merit in trying to do this on a single line. I cannot believe you got such a crappy exercise. Maybe you misunderstood the instructions. I suggest to double-check that.

Comment: That was the exercise. We did a script (no line limit) last week to get the bmp file's size and this week exercise was to re-do the same script in one line only :/ .

Comment: Try: `dd if=$1 bs=2 skip=1 count=2 2>/dev/null| od -t u4 -A n`

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Substring expansion is part of the parameter expansion, i.e. you can only use it on parameters or variables. It means it's OK to try

```
${varname:6:2}
```

but you can't use it on the output of the command substitution, unless you save it to a variable first:

```
output=$(xxd -p -seek 02 -l 4 "$1")
echo "${output:6:2}"
```

Comment: So there ain't a way to do little endian to big endian in one line without using variables ?

Comment: @VoltraNeo: Not using parameter expansion. But you can pipe the output of xxd to cut or awk or whatever to transform the string: `$(xxd ... | cut -c6-8)` etc.

Comment: To revert indianess: `read _ output _ < <(xxd -ep -seek 02 -l 4 "$1")`

Comment: But 6 bytes could be read by bash: `for((i=6;i--;)){ LC_ALL=C IFS= read -d '' -rn1 out[i] ;} <"$1"`